# Python SOAP zeep 'Client' object has no attribute 'options'

Tags: python, soap

У меня есть такой код, который работает локально и выдает ошибку на сервере Линукс:

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import xmltodict
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import json

class EtranClient:
    def __init__(self, user='username', password='pass'):
        self.user    = user.encode('utf-8')
        self.password = password.encode('utf-8')

        session = Session()
        session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(self.user, self.password)
        transport = Transport(session = session)
        self.client = Client('etran.wsdl', transport=transport)

    def mk_request(self, req):
        with self.client.options(raw_response = True):
            response = self.client.service.GetBlock(self.user,
                self.password,
                req)
            return response.content
```

Ошибка такая:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "invoice_handler.py", line 76, in <module>
>     get_invoices(conn)
>   File "invoice_handler.py", line 61, in get_invoices
>     invoice_ids = invoice.get_invoice_id_list_by_date(last_request_date)
>   File "/home/user/etran-client/invoice.py", line 52, in get_invoice_id_list_by_date
>     response = client.xml_request(request)
>   File "/home/user/etran-client/client.py", line 33, in xml_request
>     text = self.request_text_as_dict(req)
>   File "/home/user/etran-client/client.py", line 27, in request_text_as_dict
>     xml_response = self.mk_request(req)
>   File "/home/user/etran-client/client.py", line 20, in mk_request
>     with self.client.options(raw_response = True):
> AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'options'
> ```

Локально свойство options устанавливается без ошибки. Проблема возникает только на сервере. Что может быть не так?

Comment: на сервере есть 'etran.wsdl'?

Comment: Да, там все есть. Эта проблема может быть из-за того, что я писал код с версией zeep 2.5.0, а сейчас стоит 3.0.0?

Answer (score 1):

Zeep 2.5.0 has the client.options() method, the version of 3.4.0 will report the error.
You can uninstall the newest version and install the older version.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/blob/2f61894242d0090b044d53ac2ef5b756778d22c1/CHANGES) , начиная с версии 3.0.0 (2018-06-16)

> - Refactor the settings logic in Zeep. All settings are now configured using    the zeep.settings.Settings() class.

поменяй options на settings

```
client.options(raw_response = True)
```

на

```
client.settings(raw_response=True)
```

либо заинсталируй старую версию

```
pip install zeep==2.5.0
```